# How to use MongoDB to aggregate Reports for time periods within multiple days?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have pre-aggregated reports following the mongodb docs, see: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/#one-document-per-page-per-day

```
{
    _id: "20101010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
    metadata: {
        date: ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z"),
        site: "site-1",
        page: "/apache_pb.gif" },
    daily: 5468426,
    hourly: {
        "0": 227850,
        "1": 210231,
        ...
        "23": 20457 },
    minute: {
        "0": 3612,
        "1": 3241,
        ...
        "1439": 2819 }
}
```

I aggregate the views for x days back like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{ $match : { date: { $gte : ISODate("2016-04-07T00:00:00.000Z")}}},
{ $group: {_id: "_id", views: {$sum: "$daily"}}}, 
{ $sort: {views: -1}}
```

)

Now I want the views of the last x hours. The problem here is the date line. As long as I' m within the same day my solution works fine, but how to handle crossing the date line the best way?

Here is what I have:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{ $match : { date: { $eq : ISODate("2016-04-07T00:00:00.000Z")}}},
{ $group: {_id: "$_id", views: { $sum: { $add: [ '$hourly.1', '$hourly.2', ... ] }} }}, 
{ $sort: {views: -1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is my answer:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $match : { date  : { $gte : ISODate("2016-04-20T00:00:00.000Z")}}},
{ $project : {
              _id: "$_id",    
              views :
               {
                 $cond :  [ 
                   { $eq : [ "$date",  ISODate("2016-04-20T00:00:00.000Z")  ] }, 
                        { $add: [ { $ifNull : ['$hourly.22' , 0 ] } , { $ifNull : ['$hourly.23' , 0 ] } ] }, 
                        { $add: [ { $ifNull : ['$hourly.0' , 0 ] } , { $ifNull : ['$hourly.1' , 0 ] } ] }, 
                   ]
               }   
           }
 },
{ $group: { "_id" : "$_id", views: { $sum: { $add: [ "$views" ] } } }}, 
{ $sort: { views: -1}}
])
```

The $cond attribute did the trick for me, so I could distinguish the different date datasets.